# Update SO FAQ to Include Transfer Question as Something Enabled by Reputation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, faq-update-request

There are cases where questions get asked on StackOverflow, and probably are better off on ServerFault. I often times add a comment saying such, but I think it would be nice to have the ability to community vote on that, and if X number of people agree, that it gets moved over automatically. This would work similarly to voting to close or re-open a question, and would therefore require a certain reputation in order to do this.

I searched around on Meta, and haven't seen anything similar to this being asked.

As per the answer below, this is already a feature, but if you look at the [SO FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), you will see that this is not listed as one of the things that you can do in the Reputation area. I looked at that list, didn't see anything, and so I thought it was not a feature.  Perhaps the FAQ needs to be updated.  I also don't see this in the [Meta FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stack-overflow-work-the-official-faq) either.

Comment: It falls under " **3000**  Vote to close or reopen any questions ".

Comment: @fretje - That's hardly obvious from the title... or maybe thats just me.

Comment: Yes indeed, you have to know that a couple of the close reasons are "Close as belongs on ...", but once you know that, it's quite obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are given this option (voting to migrate a question) when you have 3k reputation.  It takes 5 votes to migrate.

Is there something you would like to change about the current implementation of this feature?

Comment: OK... nevermind then. I'm just not rep'd enough.

Comment: Edited question to include problems with the FAQ

Answer (score 1):

Changed to

> Vote to close, reopen, **or migrate** your questions
>   Vote to close, reopen, **or migrate** any questions

Answer (score 0):

> I often times add a comment saying
>   such

You shouldn't. After the question gets migrated the comments remain and they won't make sense anymore, and they require manual intervention from a moderator to delete.

Comment: But if you don't have enough reputation to actually do the voting, and yet you want to participate in - or start - that discussion, how do you do that?

Comment: You start by getting enough reputation to obtain the closing privilege. Don't worry, if it doesn't belong other people will notice it and migrate it.

Comment: You're supposed to flag questions that should be moved.  Click flag, select requires moderator attention, type in "belongs on wherever"

Comment: Yeah - I don't buy into the "just wait until you build your reputation" theory. I understand what reputation on SO is for, but if you see something, and actively can't take the action, I see absolutely nothing wrong with still dropping a comment. The whole point is to build a discussion, and comments by their nature are "meta".

Comment: @Ward - Is any of this described in the FAQ?

Comment: The comments are at least better than adding a belongs-on tag.

Comment: If you're going to leave a comment, explain why you think it belongs on Bar and not Foo. And I'm with Ether on this, better a comment than a tag.

Comment: It should be, here's one q&a about it:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30572/what-should-users-do-to-move-questions-to-the-more-appropriate-site